# Could someone help to explain why the klass could not be used in wrapper? About python __closure__

Tags: python, decorator

I couldn't understand why my `klass` couldn't be used in wrapper method

```
#!/usr/env/bin python

class MyClassmethod(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if not klass:
                klass = type(obj)
            return self.func(klass, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper


class Test:
    @MyClassmethod
    def mytest(cls, test=None):
        print(f"this is a classmethod belongs to {cls.__name__}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test.mytest()
```

It shows `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'klass' referenced before assignment`

But If I change the code like this, put the `klass` assignment out of the wrapper method

```
#!/usr/env/bin python

class MyClassmethod(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if not klass:
            klass = type(obj)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.func(klass, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper


class Test:
    @MyClassmethod
    def mytest(cls, test=None):
        print(f"this is a classmethod belongs to {cls.__name__}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test.mytest()
```

Could someone help to explain this？

Cheers

Comment: `klass` is a local variable inside the first version of `wrapper()` (since there's an assignment to it), unrelated to the `klass` defined in `__get__()`.  `nonlocal klass` would be one way of fixing it.

Comment: thanks @jasonharper, got it, it's  because of  `assignment`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you're referencing the variable `klass` before you've defined it.  That's not the case in the second example.